# Removing commas from multidimensional arrays

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having a bit of trouble removing commas from an array when I go to write it to a cell in google spreadsheets. array.join(''); doesn't seem to do the trick. I would appreciate any help. Also, anchor[i][j].join('') returns an error.

Here is a bit of code:

`anchor[i][j].join('')` returns an error

`anchor[i].join('')` doesn't seem to have an effect.

```
for (var i=0; i(less than) rangeKW.length-2;i++){

anchor[i] = [];

   for (var j=0; j<rangeURL.length;j++){

     anchor[i][j] = ahref + rangeKW[i] + ahref1 + rangeURL[j] + "</a>|";      

    }       
  }    
 cell.setValue("{" + anchor);      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array.join()` works with "normal" arrays, by normal I mean 1 dimension and applies to the array itself, not on an single element (error on [i][j]), beside that I don't really understand what you want to do and how your code is related to your question ...

concerning `anchor[i].join('');// doesn't seem to have an effect.` I don't know how many elements are in there and how they look like but the syntax is correct.  You can also use toString() if you want to make it a CSV string.

**EDIT :**  *(thanks for the information in comments.)*

I think the easiest way (or at least the most clear) would be to create a couple of new variables that you could log separately to see exactly what happens.

for example

```
var anchorString = anchor[i].join(); // or toString() they both return strings from 1D arrays
Logger.log(anchorString)
```

if every index i of anchor have to be in the same cell then write it like this in the i-loop :

```
var anchorString += anchor[i].join(); 
Logger.log(anchorString)
```

Comment: I'm grabbing a range of values from column A in a spreadsheet rangeKW[], then grabbing a range of values from column B rangeURL[]. Then taking rangeKW[i] and adding rangeURL[j] to every instance of rangeKW[i] with strings ahref, ahref1, and "</a>|". Hence anchor[i][j] = ahref + rangeKW[i] + ahref1 + rangeURL[j] + "</a>|"; Then writing this to a cell. So I need to remove the commas between anchor[0][0],anchor[0][1],anchor[0][2],anchor[1][0],anchor[1][1],anchor[1][2]...

Comment: Do I understand you want to write all the anchor array values contiguously in 1 cell without separations ?

Comment: Yes that sound right. Column A row 1 + Column B row 1, Column A row 1 + Column B row 2,Column A row 1 + Column B row 3...Column A row 2 + Column B row 1, Column A row 2 + Column B row 2,Column A row 2 + Column B row 3

Comment: I think your mistake was to forget that join() does not modify the string itself, it creates a new variable...

Comment: So do I need to go a regex route to remove the commas or would toString() take care of it?

Comment: toString does not... use .replace(/,/g,''), as you say ;-)

Comment: don't forget replace does not change the original string... so use a new variable again ;-)

Comment: why use an array in the first place if you just want a string? Start with an empty script e.g. `var anchor = ""` then concatenate your values, instead of pushing elements to an array, e.g. `archor += ahref + ...`

Comment: It's actually more efficient in JavaScript to go the array route, because string additions are slow. I'd recommend doing it with arrays and then using one of the answers I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have

```
  var x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Then either of these lines will give you "123456":

```
  Array.prototype.concat.apply([], x).join('')
  x.map(function(a){ return a.join(''); }).join('');
```

The first one constructs the array [1,2,3,4,5,6] and then joins it. The second one joins each inner array first, constructing ["123", "456"] and then joins that. I think the first one is likely to be a tiny bit more efficient, although we are talking peanuts here, but the second one gives you a bit more control if you want to put something different between rows and columns.

In both cases, this doesn't change the original value in x. You can assign the new value to x if that's what you want.